# Replicating a chropleth in D3.js using d3.tsv

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gdal, topojson

I'm trying to replicate [Mike Bostock's chropleth](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606) using a topojson file of mexican municipalties and coloring it using a .tsv with matching id values to the polygons.

So far I've been able to show the map and its polygons but I can't to get to actually color it based on the values from the .tsv file.

[image]

I suspect the problem is in this function as I'm not entirely sure where its calling the .tsv inside the function

```
    queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "mx5.topojson")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "Cosecha.tsv", function(d) { rateById.set(d.id, +d.rate); })
    .await(ready);

function ready(error, mx5) {
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "mx4")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(mx5, mx5.objects.mx4).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return quantize(rateById.get(d.id)); })
      .attr("d", path);

 svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(mx5, mx5.objects.Estados, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "Estados")
      .attr("d", path);

}
```

Here is a link to my [gist](https://gist.github.com/EduardoClark/dc2638735b6e93615f8e) and here one to my topojson of [mexican municipalities](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/topojson/mx5.topojson)

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code expects counties to be indexed by prop `id`, e.g. `rateById.set(d.id, +d.rate)`.

However, your tsv calls them `"Mun"`, as in

```
"Mun"   "rate"
"01001" 350058.5
"01002" 224305
"01003" 132115
```

So change `d.id` to `d.Mun` (in 2 places), or rename `"Mun"`